# Parameters of transformer: open-circuit test and short-circuit test

Tags: transformer

Ok I have the following circuit and data (when the subscript is "ef" it means "rms" values):

[image]

I am asked to determine the paramenters of the transformer r1 L11, L22 and LM with the given experimental data.

I had no problem extracting data from the open circuit experiment. 
Using the fact that the active power is given by
$$P=r_1 I_{rms}^2$$

I found $$r_1=10 \Omega$$

Then applying induction law  in both primary and secondary leaves us with:

$$u_1(t)=r_1i_1(t)+L_{11}\frac{di_1(t)}{dt}$$
$$u_2(t)=-L_{M}\frac{di_1(t)}{dt}$$

Applying phasor notation and taking the rms values will lead us to obtain

$$L_M=\frac{U_{2_{rms}}}{\omega I_{1_{rms}} }=31.83 mH$$
$$L_{11}=\sqrt{(\frac{U_{1_{rms}}^2}{I_{1_{rms}}^2} - r_1^2) \frac{1}{\omega^2}}=55.13 mH$$

Ok and there is no more data we can extract form the open-circuit experiment.

Passing to the short-circuit experiment I will obtain from induction law again:

$$0=-L_{M}\frac{di_1(t)}{dt}-L_{22}\frac{di_2(t)}{dt}$$

Which leads to

$$L_{22}=\frac{L_M I_{1_{rms}}}{I_{2_{rms}} }$$

Problem now is I don't know the value of the root-mean square of current 2 and have no idea how to find it out. 
My guess is that I need to use the reactive power. But how? 
I know from Poynting complex theorem:

$$P_Q= 2\omega ((W_e)_{av} - (W_m)_{av})$$

But, and that is another question I have and would like to get ans answer on?
How should I apply this formula. 
For the electrical energy, should I take the capacitor? But what's the voltage value? The same as the open-circuit experiment?
And for the magnetic energy? What inductances  should I consider? Do I need to calculate an equivalent circuit?

I'm really confused and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be calculating the mutual inductance by considering the open circuit secondary but I can't see how this can be done without knowing both the coupling, the output voltage and the secondary inductance. Maybe I missed something? Also, the primary inductance (L11) does not involve U2 although I get the same answer - maybe you typoed.

Comment: Hi! It can be done applying the induction law as I did! Because I obtain it with the relation between u2 and i1. Because the current i2 is zero... Yes it was a typo, thanks! How would you calculate the coupling and the secondary inductanc?

Comment: On the short-circuit test, the primary voltage is lowered so there's the rated secondary current drawn at secondary short circuit.

Comment: Janka I don't understand what you said and how it helps me

Comment: Anyone please??

Comment: How does \$i_2\$ flow in the open circuit experiment? I can't see the loop for that current.

Comment: @SvenB It doesn't. The current is zero

Comment: No problem, can you help me?

Comment: Why downvoting? LOL

Answer (score 1):

The closed circuit experiment will yield two equations instead of one:

$$\begin{align}
u_1(t) &= r_1i_1(t) + L_{11}\frac{di_1}{dt} - L_M\frac{di_2}{dt}\\
u_2(t) &= r_2i_2(t) - L_M\frac{di_1}{dt} + L_{22}\frac{di_2}{dt}
\end{align}$$

(Note that the signs may need to be changed)

Meaning it will have 2 equations and 2 unknowns (\$i_1(t)\$ and \$i_2(t)\$), which can be solved.

[Edit]

For your short-circuit experiment and when using phasors, this would result into something like:

$$\begin{align}
\underline{U_1} &= \left(r_1 + j\omega L_{11}\right) \underline{I_1} - j\omega L_M \underline{I_2}\\
0 &= -j\omega L_M \underline{I_1} + \left(r_2 + j\omega L_{22}\right) \underline{I_2}
\end{align}$$

The solution to this set of equations will be two complex values for \$\underline{I_1}\$ and \$\underline{I_2}\$. You can take the absolute value like with any phasor.

$$\underline{U_1} = U_{RMS}\cdot \sqrt{2}$$

$$I_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{\text{re}[\underline{I}]^2+\text{im}[\underline{I}]^2}{2}}$$

And you can calculate the complex power as well

$$\underline{P} = \underline{U_1}\cdot\underline{I_1}^*$$

Comment: How the hell do I work with this equations? I need to pass to phasor form but then how do I take the module? Because I will have the sum of phasor I1 and phasor I2 I have no idea on how to take absolute values. Can you be more specific than that?

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: can you help me please?